# How to define entity property not possible to describe by associations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I am writing a vocabulary learning application.
I have a Wordset Entity.
I want it to contain a property - WordsToLearn (a collection of words to learn for a CURRENT user, words which are either new, i.e no repetitions for current user or have Repetition due today or earlier)

How can I implement this?

Without this my object seems very incomplete.
Are entities limited to simple relationships and I should forget about it in this place and move it to Wordset Repository. 
I would be very useful to be able to get that information (wordsToLearn) from Wordset Object

Answer (score 0):

Yes, entities are limited to these simple relationships. For more complex queries you have to use a [WordsetRepository](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) that you can pass your current_user object to and use that to get the desired entities in your controllers. You can use Doctrine's DQL to fetch 'real' entity objects instead of just SQL results.